# Update a field if another field has a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a MySQL database but only if a field has the value `Approved`.

If `status` is `Approved` then `Date approved` should update with the date.

Below is the code I am currently using but cannot get it to work. How to get it to work?

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET `FieldValue`= IF(FieldName='status' AND FieldValue='Approved','".date('m/d/Y')."','') 
WHERE `SubmissionId`=".$SubmissionId." 
AND FieldName='Date Approved'
```

Sample Data

```
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| FormId | SubmissionId |   FieldName   |  FieldValue  |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|      6 |          778 | status        | Not Approved |
|      6 |          778 | Date Approved |              |
+--------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: so, you want to do it by sql query? you can also do it in programmatic way.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: first of all create a function for checking where `submissionId=$submissionId` and if the `status` is `approved` then return true and if that function returns true then update the `dateApproved` field.

Comment: Why are you not doing this with the Joomla API? What actual error message are you getting when you run that in phpMyAdmin or similar?  There are a lot of other questions we would need the answers to know why it's not working.

Comment: This is a bad design for a database; it looks appealing until you try to do things like what you're trying to do, for example. It is known as [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) — Entity, Attribute, Value — and is generally regarded as a design that make it very difficult to write insert, delete, update, and even select operations, and also very difficult to maintain referential integrity. In fact, the only thing it makes easy is the undisciplined addition of new attributes. In your case, the entity is identified by the FormID and the SubmissionID.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement like below:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET `FieldValue` = CASE WHEN FieldName = 'status' 
AND FieldValue='Approved' THEN date('m/d/Y') ELSE `FieldValue` END 
WHERE `SubmissionId` = $SubmissionId;
```

But your query won't make sense; your `FieldValue` column looks like a string type column and you are trying store a date type data.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Fields to update.
$fields = array(
$db->quoteName('FieldValue') . ' = ' . $date->toSql('m/d/Y'))
);

// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = array(
$db->quoteName('SubmissionId') . ' = SubmissionId', 
$db->quoteName('FieldValue') . ' = ' . $db->quote('Approved')
);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__my_table'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

$db->setQuery($query);

$result = $db->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Superficially, you should be using the raw SQL like this:

```
UPDATE my_table
      SET FieldValue = date('m/d/Y') 
    WHERE SubmissionId = 778
      AND FieldName = 'Date Approved'
   -- AND FieldValue IS NULL   -- Optional
   -- AND FormId = 6           -- Optional
      AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM my_table
                   WHERE FieldName = 'status'
                     AND FieldValue = 'Approved'
                     AND SubmissionId = 778
                  -- AND FormId = 6    -- Optional
                 )
```

You might need to tart things up a little to get values embedded into the string that forms the SQL statement.

You don't mention FormID in your query; in case of doubt, you should constrain the UPDATE with the correct FormID value, twice, like you constrain the SubmissionID value twice (as shown in the comments).  You might decide you only want to update the 'Date Approved' field name when it is NULL (or perhaps blank).

I note that one of the problem with this [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) design is that you lose the type-checking that a normal design gives you.  You could store a date (as intended), or a pure number, or pure text, or anything else in the `FieldValue` column for the 'Date Approved' `FieldName` and there's nothing to stop that abuse happening.  If you had an orthodox typed column, you could ensure that non-dates were never stored in the 'Date Approved' column.

Your UPDATE is tied to a single submission ID; so is mine.  It should be possible to enhance things so that all the uninitialized 'Date Approved' columns that are approved and have not previously had the 'Date Approved' value set do in fact have it set.